# delete query (Mysql, Php)

Tags: php, mysql

i tried to delete a mysql table record by a columname (ID).

```
if(isset($_GET['del_termin_del'])){
        $del_del_del = $_GET['del_termin_del'];
        $del_query = "DELETE FROM termine WHERE TerminID = '.$del_del_del.'";
        if ($conni->query($del_query) === TRUE) {
            echo "erfolgreich";
        } else {
            echo "Fehler beim Löschen" . $conn->error;
        }
}
```

If i run this, i get the success message, but the record is still there.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You really need to look at how to use bound parameters here. This is wide open to SQL injection, and your code makes it possible for someone to empty your entire table in one go!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the dots in your query.

```
"DELETE FROM termine WHERE TerminID = '.$del_del_del.'"
```

to

```
"DELETE FROM termine WHERE TerminID = '$del_del_del'";
```

then everything should work!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query

```
> "DELETE FROM termine WHERE TerminID = '.$del_del_del.'";
```

with

```
"DELETE FROM termine WHERE TerminID = '$del_del_del'";
```

Comment: oh that's it :) Thank you for the quick and right answer

Comment: i have to wait 9 minutes